TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function.....In Node.js
I'm working with node.js and got an error.
An unexpected error occurred:
Error: ERROR processing skip func of /root/hardhat-nft-fcc/deploy/02-deploy-random-ipfs-nft.js:
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

this is my 02-random-nft-deploy
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")
const { storeImages } = require("../utils/uploadToPinata")

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("30")
const imagesLocation = "./images/randomNFT/"

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log, get } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (process.env.UPLOAD_TO_PINATA == "true") {
        tokenUris = await handleTokenUris()
    }

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        // Get the deployment of VRFCoordinatorV2Mock
        const vrfCoordinatorV2MockDeployment = await get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")

        // Get the signer object for the deployer
        const signer = await ethers.getSigner(deployer)

        // Get the contract instance using ethers with the correct signer
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt(
            "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",
            vrfCoordinatorV2MockDeployment.address,
            signer,
        )

        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait()
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId.toString()

        // Fund the subscription
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    log("----------------------------")
    await storeImages(imagesLocation)
    // const args = [
    //     vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
    //     subscriptionId,
    //     networkConfig[chainId].gaslane,
    //     networkConfig[chainId].callbackGasLimit,
    //     //tokenUris,
    //     networkConfig[chainId].mintFee,
    // ]
}
async function handleTokenUris() {
    tokenUris = []
    // store the image in IPFS
    // store the metadata in IPFS

    return tokenUris
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "main", "randomipfs"]

this is my uploadToPinata.js
const pinataSDK = require("@pinata/sdk")
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")
require("dotenv").config()

const pinataApiKey = process.env.PINATA_API_KEY || ""
const pinataApiSecret = process.env.PINATA_API_SECRET || ""
const pinata = pinataSDK(pinataApiKey, pinataApiSecret)

async function storeImages(imagesFilePath) {
    const fullImagePath = path.resolve(imagesFilePath)
    const files = fs.readdirSync(fullImagePath)
    let responses = []
    console.log("Uploading to Pinata!")
    for (const fileIndex of files) {
        console.log(`Working on ${fileIndex}...`)
        const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream(`${fullImagePath}/${fileIndex}`)
        try {
            const response = await pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile)
            responses.push(response)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return { responses, files }
}

module.exports = { storeImages }


I don't know what a class is here, which I'm considering as a function.
I will be thankful to you guys if anyone helps me.

Is that the full stacktrace?
